# examine if series is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have problem with

$$ a_n=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{\left\lfloor{\frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1}} \right\rfloor}\cdot\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$

I'd like to use here a dirichlet's test I know how to show $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ is decreasing and goes to $0$ so we need only show that the partial sum
 $$ b_n=\sum_{n=2}^{N}(-1)^{\left\lfloor{\frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1}} \right\rfloor}$$

is bounded

Comment: Differentiate $\frac{\ln x}{x}$.

Comment: sorry I've forgotten to add that I'm not allowed to differentiate and integrate.

Comment: I don't see an obvious reason that the partial sum of the $(-1)$ terms should be bounded.  Perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: yeah for sure it's not obvious (at least for me) but wolfram shows it's bounded

Comment: So are you "allowed to differentiate" then?

Comment: $$\frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1} \approx \frac{n}{3},$$ you could look at that, to see the boundedness.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see it but how to apply it to the boundedness ? Can I do something like: $\displaystyle a_n=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{\left\lfloor{\frac{n^3+n+1}{3n^2-1}} \right\rfloor} \le   b_n=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{\left\lfloor{\frac{n}{3}} \right\rfloor}$ and since $b_n$ is bounded then $a_n$ is too ?

Comment: Not quite, the equality of the floors starts at $3$, not at $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing the previous answer, note that
$$
\frac{n^3 +n + 1}{3n^2 - 1} = \frac 13 n + \frac 43 \frac{n}{3n^2 - 1} =\frac{n}{3}+v_n,
$$
and 
$$
0<v_n<\frac{1}{3},
$$
for all $n\ge 2$. Thus
$$
(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n^3 +n + 1}{3n^2 - 1}\right\rfloor}=1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,\cdots.
$$
**Note.** The fact that $v_n=O(1/n)$ is not enough to get convergence! It is important to note that $v_n>0$!

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\frac{n^3 +n + 1}{3n^2 - 1} = \frac 13 n + \frac 43 \frac{n}{3n^2 - 1} = \frac 13 n + O(1/n)
$$
It follows that for sufficiently large $n$, the sequence
$
(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac{n^3 +n + 1}{3n^2 - 1}\right\rfloor}
$
will have the form
$$
\{\dots 1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,\dots\}
$$
So that the partial sum cannot exceed the value it attains before this sufficiently large $n$.